# Calculate gst for receipt

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is actually for a shop receipt but i need to regenerate it into a school receipt. ie, i need the tax1 value auto generate as 5% and tax2 auto genetrate as 6% and calculate it 
and also no quantity needed.

```
   <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
   var final_total_amt = $('#final_total_amt').text();
   var count = 1;

   $(document).on('click', '#add_row', function(){
    count++;
    $('#total_item').val(count);
    var html_code = '';
    html_code += '<tr id="row_id_'+count+'">';
    html_code += '<td><span id="sr_no">'+count+'</span></td>';



     html_code += '<td><input type="text" name="item_name[]" id="item_name'+count+'" class="form-control input-sm" /></td>';

      html_code += '<td><input type="text" name="order_item_quantity[]" id="order_item_quantity'+count+'" data-srno="'+count+'" class="form-control input-sm number_only order_item_quantity" /></td>';
      html_code += '<td><input type="text" name="order_item_price[]" id="order_item_price'+count+'" data-srno="'+count+'" class="form-control input-sm number_only order_item_price" /></td>';
      html_code += '<td><input type="text" name="order_item_actual_amount[]" id="order_item_actual_amount'+count+'" data-srno="'+count+'" class="form-control input-sm order_item_actual_amount" readonly /></td>';

      html_code += '<td><input type="text" name="order_item_tax1_rate[]" id="order_item_tax1_rate'+count+'" data-srno="'+count+'" class="form-control input-sm number_only order_item_tax1_rate" /></td>';
      html_code += '<td><input type="text" name="order_item_tax1_amount[]" id="order_item_tax1_amount'+count+'" data-srno="'+count+'" readonly class="form-control input-sm order_item_tax1_amount" /></td>';
      html_code += '<td><input type="text" name="order_item_tax2_rate[]" id="order_item_tax2_rate'+count+'" data-srno="'+count+'" class="form-control input-sm number_only order_item_tax2_rate" /></td>';
      html_code += '<td><input type="text" name="order_item_tax2_amount[]" id="order_item_tax2_amount'+count+'" data-srno="'+count+'" readonly class="form-control input-sm order_item_tax2_amount" /></td>';
      html_code += '<td><input type="text" name="order_item_tax3_rate[]" id="order_item_tax3_rate'+count+'" data-srno="'+count+'" class="form-control input-sm number_only order_item_tax3_rate" /></td>';
      html_code += '<td><input type="text" name="order_item_tax3_amount[]" id="order_item_tax3_amount'+count+'" data-srno="'+count+'" readonly class="form-control input-sm order_item_tax3_amount" /></td>';
      html_code += '<td><input type="text" name="order_item_final_amount[]" id="order_item_final_amount'+count+'" data-srno="'+count+'" readonly class="form-control input-sm order_item_final_amount" /></td>';
      html_code += '<td><button type="button" name="remove_row" id="'+count+'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs remove_row">X</button></td>';


     html_code += '</tr>';
      $('#invoice-item-table').append(html_code);
      });

     $(document).on('click', '.remove_row', function(){
      var row_id = $(this).attr("id");
      var total_item_amount = $('#order_item_final_amount'+row_id).val();
      var final_amount = $('#final_total_amt').text();
      var result_amount = parseFloat(final_amount) - parseFloat(total_item_amount);
      $('#final_total_amt').text(result_amount);
      $('#row_id_'+row_id).remove();
      count--;
      $('#total_item').val(count);
     });

     function cal_final_total(count)
     {
      var final_item_total = 0;
      for(j=1; j<=count; j++)
      {
        var quantity = 0;
        var price = 0;
        var actual_amount = 0;
        var tax1_rate = 0;
        var tax1_amount = 0;
        var tax2_rate = 0;
        var tax2_amount = 0;
        var tax3_rate = 0;
        var tax3_amount = 0;
        var item_total = 0;
        quantity = $('#order_item_quantity'+j).val();
        if(quantity > 0)
        {
          price = $('#order_item_price'+j).val();
          if(price > 0)
          {
            actual_amount = parseFloat(quantity) * parseFloat(price);
            $('#order_item_actual_amount'+j).val(actual_amount);
            tax1_rate = $('#order_item_tax1_rate'+j).val();
            if(tax1_rate > 0)
            {
              tax1_amount = parseFloat(actual_amount)*parseFloat(tax1_rate)/100;
              $('#order_item_tax1_amount'+j).val(tax1_amount);
            }
            tax2_rate = $('#order_item_tax2_rate'+j).val();
            if(tax2_rate > 0)
            {
              tax2_amount = parseFloat(actual_amount)*parseFloat(tax2_rate)/100;
              $('#order_item_tax2_amount'+j).val(tax2_amount);
            }
            tax3_rate = $('#order_item_tax3_rate'+j).val();
            if(tax3_rate > 0)
            {
              tax3_amount = parseFloat(actual_amount)*parseFloat(tax3_rate)/100;
              $('#order_item_tax3_amount'+j).val(tax3_amount);
            }
            item_total = parseFloat(actual_amount) + parseFloat(tax1_amount) + parseFloat(tax2_amount) + parseFloat(tax3_amount);
            final_item_total = parseFloat(final_item_total) + parseFloat(item_total);
            $('#order_item_final_amount'+j).val(item_total);
              }
           }
            }
         $('#final_total_amt').text(final_item_total);
          }

          $(document).on('blur', '.order_item_price', function(){
            cal_final_total(count);
          });

          $(document).on('blur', '.order_item_tax1_rate', function(){
            cal_final_total(count);
          });

          $(document).on('blur', '.order_item_tax2_rate', function(){
            cal_final_total(count);
          });

          $(document).on('blur', '.order_item_tax3_rate', function(){
            cal_final_total(count);
          });

          $('#create_invoice').click(function(){
            if($.trim($('#order_receiver_name').val()).length == 0)
            {
              alert("Please Enter Reciever Name");
              return false;
            }

            if($.trim($('#order_no').val()).length == 0)
            {
              alert("Please Enter Invoice Number");
              return false;
            }

            if($.trim($('#order_date').val()).length == 0)
            {
              alert("Please Select Invoice Date");
              return false;
            }

            for(var no=1; no<=count; no++)
            {
              if($.trim($('#item_name'+no).val()).length == 0)
              {
                alert("Please Enter Item Name");
                $('#item_name'+no).focus();
                return false;
              }

              if($.trim($('#order_item_quantity'+no).val()).length == 0)
              {
                alert("Please Enter Quantity");
                $('#order_item_quantity'+no).focus();
                return false;
              }

              if($.trim($('#order_item_price'+no).val()).length == 0)
              {
                alert("Please Enter Price");
                $('#order_item_price'+no).focus();
                return false;
              }

            }

            $('#invoice_form').submit();

          });

        });
        </script>
```

I dont know how to recode this to a school receipt. please any can recode this with this same values like no quanitity required , tax1 should be having default value as 5% and tax2 with value 6% and calculate it

Comment: ok do you want the tax percentage as autogiven and caculate with the given amount right??

Comment: yes can any one help me on this